# Comparing 2 array with recursive function without LOOP

Tags: c++, function, recursion

```
bool areEqual(int *A1, int size1, int *A2, int size2)
{
int index = 0;
if (size1 != size2) 
    return false;

else if (A1[index] != A2[index])
    return false;
else
{
    index++;
    areEqual(A1, size1, A2, size2);
}
return true;
}
```

I'm working with this recursive function but every time two array have the same size. It returns Stack Overflow. Why's that? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Your subject line ("recursive function without LOOP") is a bit redundant  ;)  "stack overflow" means that whatever your inputs ... they never satisfy any of your "exit" conditions ... so you recurse infinitely.  Crash!  My first guess is that "size1" is never >= 0, so you call areEqual() with the same values ... over and over, forever.  SUGGESTION: *Step through your code with a debugger*!!!!

Comment: the return value of the only recursive call in your code is dropped ... all 'areEqual()' invocations are required to return a bool (by your definition).

Answer (score 0):

`index` is always `0`.
You should pass it as a parameter and check, or it won't end.

```
bool areEqual(int *A1, int size1, int *A2, int size2, int index=0)
{
    if (size1 != size2) return false; 
    if (index == size1) return true;

    if (A1[index] != A2[index]) return false;
    return areEqual(A1, size1, A2, size2, index+1);
}
```

You can split it into 2 functions, which is more clear.

```
bool areEqualRecursive(const int *A1, const int *A2, const int size, int index){
    if (index == size) return true;
    
    if (A1[index] != A2[index]) return false;
    return areEqualRecursive(A1, A2, size, index+1);
}

bool areEqual(const int *A1, const int size1, const int *A2, const int size2){
    if(size1 != size2) return false;
    if(A1 == A2) return true;
    
    return areEqualRecursive(A1, A2, size1, 0);
}
```

Calling in both cases:

```
bool is_equal = areEqual(arr1, size1, arr2, size2);
```

Comment: Yes i fix it, can you check it for me again please...

Comment: @HoangMy You should check the bounds too. In your updated question, you must check if `index` is not lower than `0`

Answer (score 0):

Your version call exactly with the same argument, creating infinite recursion.

Possible option without extra parameter:

```
bool areEqual(const int* A1, int size1, const int* A2, int size2)
{
    if (size1 != size2) return false; 
    if (size1 == 0) return true; // end of array

    if (A1[0] != A2[0]) return false; // current char differs
    return areEqual(A1 + 1, size1 - 1, A2 + 1, size2 - 1);
}
```